# Help! I’m afraid to fully set up Ubuntu because of this problem!

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, usb-drive, usb-installation

I'm trying to put Ubuntu on a USB stick that I can run anywhere. I have completed the first few steps (installing the .iso, installing PenDrive Linux, etc.) and it works perfectly, except for actually setting it up. When I get to the part about "unmounting partitions", I say no because I'm afraid of deleting anything on my Windows 10.

Then I choose not to wipe the drive and instead choose *Something else*. This is where I need help. I have no idea what to select or what not to, all I want is to have it set up on my pen drive and leave my main OS unscathed. I also don't know what to select in the dropdown menu in the partition settings. I have photos at https://kayo.moe/6eIoeRCy.jpeg and https://kayo.moe/CbunbdqV.jpeg, but that's probably not much of a help. Just ask and I will send more.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install to the same drive as you are booting with the live installer? That is a bit tricky, much better to use a smaller flash drive with live installer & larger flash drive for full install. You need to use Something Else as that is the only way you get to select where to install grub2's boot loader. And you want it installed to flash drive with full install, not installer nor Windows drive. Ubuntu now has default install of just / (root). You just need to select or create new / partition as ext4 and as / using change button if partition exists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jump drive is on /dev/sdb. If you can confirm that that's true, then making changes to partitions on your /dev/sdb won't effect /dev/sda (which presumably must be your Windows drive if /dev/sdb is your jump drive).

Unmounting partitions, even your Windows partition, won't effect any of the data on that partition. However be careful not to delete or reformat partitions on your Windows drive.

All that said, the images you linked to all show that operations will be done on /dev/sdb (which, if that's your jump drive, is what you want)

I think it's safe to continue. I would advise you to make sure you have backups before you do though. I would advise you to make backups even if you weren't having any issues installing Ubuntu and even if you weren't trying to install anything at all.

Comment: New problem - what do I select in the “use as” drop down of /dev/sdb1? It seems like no matter what I choose, it says “no root file system is defined”. Also, I don’t know what mount point to choose. Sorry, I’m bad with computers and am absolutely brand new to Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexCDG For a typical single-partition installation, "use as" should be set to `/`.